# Grid alternative for FlowDocument?

Tags: c#, wpf

From what I read, a Grid cannot be used inside a FlowDocument.

```
 <TextBlock Margin="0 10" FontFamily="Ubuntu"  FontSize="19" FontWeight="DemiBold" Text="Account details"></TextBlock>
 <Separator  Width="600"></Separator>
 <StackPanel Margin="0 10" Orientation="Horizontal">

       <TextBlock Margin="0 0 30 0"  Text="Account ID"></TextBlock>
       <TextBlock Margin="0 0 30 0" Text="Username"></TextBlock>
       <TextBlock Margin="0 0 30 0"  Text="Password"></TextBlock>
       <TextBlock Margin="0 0 30 0"  Text="Creation date"></TextBlock>

    </StackPanel>
 <Separator  Width="600"></Separator>
  <StackPanel Margin="0 10" Orientation="Horizontal">

    <TextBlock  Width="102" Margin="0 0 30 0"  ></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock  Width="Auto" Margin="0 0 30 0" ></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock   Width="Auto" Margin="0 0 30 0"  ></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock   Width="91" Margin="0 0 30 0"  ></TextBlock>

  </StackPanel>

 </StackPanel>
```

The output:

[image]

The problem now is that If I fill the `Textblock's` in the second StackPanel, they won't show all the text If they're long, which is expected since I have set a specific width to them. If I set it to `Auto` It's going to show, but the content each `Textblock` won't align with the columns and It will be messier.

What are my current options?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a kind of grid in your `FlowDocument` (i.e. you want to draw a table) you can use the [Table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.table?view=netframework-4.7.2) class. It derives from the [Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.block?view=netframework-4.7.2) element, so it can be contained in a `FlowDocument`.

`Table` is pretty easy to use:

```
<FlowDocument>
  <Table>
    <!-- 
      This table has 3 columns, each described by a TableColumn 
      element nested in a Table.Columns collection element. 
    -->
    <Table.Columns>
      <TableColumn />
      <TableColumn />
      <TableColumn />
    </Table.Columns>
    <!-- 
      This table includes a single TableRowGroup which hosts 2 rows,
      each described by a TableRow element.
    -->
    <TableRowGroup>
      <!--
        Each of the 2 TableRow elements hosts 3 cells, described by
        TableCell elements.
      -->
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
          <!-- 
            TableCell elements may only host elements derived from Block.
            In this example, Paragaph elements serve as the ultimate content
            containers for the cells in this table.
          -->
          <Paragraph>Cell at Row 1 Column 1</Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>Cell at Row 1 Column 2</Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>Cell at Row 1 Column 3</Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
      <TableRow>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>Cell at Row 2 Column 1</Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>Cell at Row 2 Column 2</Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
        <TableCell>
          <Paragraph>Cell at Row 2 Column 3</Paragraph>
        </TableCell>
      </TableRow>
    </TableRowGroup>
  </Table>
</FlowDocument>
```

You can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/table-overview).
I hope it can help you.